# uninstall npm package from angular

Tags: angular, npm

I am firing below command on command line and on gitBash

```
npm -g uninstall angualar2piwik --save
```

but it says

```
up to date in 0.16s
```

and it does not remove entry from package.json nor it removes node_modules as well.

I tried with admin rights as well.

please assist.

Answer (score 2):

Open your project's **package.json**,

- remove the entry for **angualar2piwik** from **dependencies**  in pacakge.json.

  ```
  "angualar2piwik": "version"
  ```
- hit **npm install** command

**angualar2piwik** package will be removed from node modules once **npm install is over**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
npm uninstall [<@scope>/]<pkg>[@<version>]... [-S|--save|-D|--save-dev|-O|--save-optional|--no-save]
```

**For Specific package, try this**

```
npm uninstall packageName
```

i.e. `npm uninstall node-tap`